# QGIS Proportionla Circle Legend

Tags: gis, qgis

I have a problem adding a circle proportional legend in print composer. When I add it it looks like when in the picture; not vertically aligned.

I tried with all legend properties without success!

Comment: Your image is not showing up

Comment: Removed image tag as there is no link to it.